# $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[yp] = p\mathbb{E}[Y]$

Tags: probability

Its given $\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] = yp$

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] = \mathbb{E}[yp] =  p\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

What I do not understand is the 3rd to last step. Can I just change $\mathbb{E}[y]$ to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ like that? Or is this not what happens?

Comment: Are you quite sure it said "$=yp$" rather than $=Yp$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand you have
$$E[X\mid Y=y]=yp=f(y)$$
Since the value of $Y$ is random, this means that $E[X\mid Y]$ (without writing $Y=$ something) is a random variable, so it makes sense to take expectation. More precisely, it is the random variable $pY$ (you can in fact define  a random variable with any real valued function $f(y)$ whose domain contains the support of the random variable $Y$ and denote it $f(Y)$).

The double expectation theorem reads as:
$$ E[X]=E[E[X\mid Y]]$$
notice that it would not have had a lot of sense to write $E[E[X\mid Y=y]]$ since in this case $E[X\mid Y=y]$ is a fixed number, a realization (since $y$ "small caps" is a number not a random variable). This nonetheless is a very commonly seen notation.

So your formula should be
$$ E[X]=E[E[X\mid Y]] = E[pY] =  pE[Y] .$$
Also a nice thing to do whenever you use your formula is to make it clear what is the variable that the function $E$ is considering. That is,
$$ \sum_{\mathrm{supp}(X)} xP(X=x)= E_X[X]=E_Y[E[X\mid Y]] = \sum_{\mathrm{supp}(Y)} E[X\mid Y=y]P(Y=y).$$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X | Y] = yp$ actually comes from $X \sim \mathcal{B}(y,p)$, so $\mathbb{E}[X]=yp$. So you are saying, the $y$ should be written $Y$ instead?

Comment: $Y$ is a random variable, and you know the distribution of $X$ whenever you know the value $Y$ actually takes, so you should write $X\mid Y=y \sim B(y,p)$. However in order to know the unconditional expected value of $X$ you need to know the expected value of $Y$ the random variable. The fact that you know how $X$ behaves given a certain realization $y$ of $Y$ means little unless you know how often $Y$ takes this value. In order to "guess" the value of $X$ you need to have a guess of the value of $Y$. That's why $E[X]=pE[Y]$, it is $p$ times your guess for $Y$.

Comment: So yes, it is better to write $E[X\mid Y]=pY$ as something different from $E[X\mid Y=y]=yp$, the first one is a new random variable and the second one the expected value of a random variable.